Automate running and unpacking SFX file with password using Python
I am currently trying to automate the extraction of an SFX file while using Python. Is there any way I can automate:

running the .exe
enter the password
retry if the password wasn't correct?
Thanks very much for your help!
-q

I tried using the "regular" Framework for zip-files which did not work, due to wrong datatypes.
